# PHP auto-reply email

Tags: php, email

Newbie at Php but managed to get this up, running and working great. They now would like to have an auto reply email sent to the patient filling out the online form. I don't care what I add…It just docent seem to sen d any rely emails. Could anyone please help me out before I start asking for some meds. :/
Thank you so much.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name_of_medication = $_POST['name_of_medication'];
$strength_dosage = $_POST['strength_dosage'];
$amount_taken_daily = $_POST['amount_taken_daily'];
$would_like_a = $_POST['would_like_a'];
$would_like = $_POST['would_like'];
$pharmacy_address = $_POST['pharmacy_address'];
$message = $_POST['message']; //-- all above info to be filled out by patient --//

$formcontent=" From: $name \n Name of Medication: $name_of_medication \n Strength 
/ Dosage: $strength_dosage \n Amount Taken Daily: $amount_taken_daily \n I would like a: 
$would_like_a \n I would like: $would_like \n Pharmacy Name: $pharmacy \n 
      Pharmacy  Address:
$pharmacy_address \n Message/Notes: $message";
$recipient = "prescription@mydoctor.com";
$subject = "Prescription Request Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Your Prescription Request has been received and will be processed within 48 hours.
  Thank you!" ;

//-- all above info to be emailed to our doctor's office --//

$formcontent2=" From: $name \n Name of Medication: $name_of_medication \n Strength 
 / Dosage: $strength_dosage \n Amount Taken Daily: $amount_taken_daily \n 
 I would like a:
$would_like_a \n I would like: $would_like \n Pharmacy Name: $pharmacy \n 
Pharmacy Address: $pharmacy_address \n Message/Notes: $message";
$recipient = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Prescription Request Form";
$mailheader = "prescription@mydoctor.com";
mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

//-- all above info to be auto (auto reply) emailed to patient --//

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your $mailheader variable to this

```
$mailheader= "From: prescription@mydoctor.com";
```